# Query every n rows in POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table in postgresql, say

| id | fname |
| --- | --- |
| abc | bert |
| def | jaap |
| ghi | kees |
| jkl | jan |
| etc | piet |

...etc...

With a `string` primary key `id`.

My table has millions of rows.

I want to get a list of every 10_000th (give or take) row.

Basically:

```
SELECT id 
FROM (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rownum 
  FROM mytable
) as t 
WHERE ((t.rownum - 1) % 10000) = 0;
```

But that seems to be very slow. Is there an efficient alternative?

Comment: [`TABLESAMPLE`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TABLESAMPLE_Implementation) comes into mind. But if that's useful to you depends on how accurate the every 10k have to be.

Comment: What is a "user"?

Comment: Please use numbers.  How many millions?  How slow is it?  How fast do you need it to be?  What is the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) <query>`, preferably after turning track_io_timing on?

Comment: @gordon-linoff what user?

Comment: @sticky-bit interesting function, I never heard of it before. It seems to pick a number of samples, this requires me to know the exact row number beforehand?

Comment: @Maarten: It needs you to know how many rows or what percentage of all rows are equivalent to roughly pick every 10k rows, yes. And of course the gaps can vary greatly. In an extreme case it's also possible to pick up two consecutive rows.

Comment: I guess I have tolerance for statistical outliers. Would you expect it to perform better than `ntile`? Thank you! If you promote the comment to an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Maarten: I'm sorry but I don't *know*, if it's gonna be faster. I think there's a good chance it will, but you have to test that for yourself to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could try NTILE()-function

```
WITH CTE(ID,FNAME)AS
 (
    SELECT 'ABC','BERT'
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'DEF','JAAP'
        UNION  ALL
    SELECT 'GHI','KEES'
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'JKL','JAN'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ETC','PIET'
 )
 SELECT C.ID,C.FNAME,
     NTILE(3)OVER(ORDER BY C.ID ASC)XCOL 
      FROM CTE AS C;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that it might be the best possible solution. I have executed your below query in sql server on a table having almost 65 million rows and getting result with 18 seconds. I think it might be the best possible solution. Since it's primary key column a cluster is already there to speed up the process. If you regularly do the maintenance job it might be the best you can  ask for.

```
SELECT id 
FROM (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rownum 
  FROM mytable
) as t 
WHERE ((t.rownum - 1) % 10000) = 0;
```

Please let me know the exact row numbers and your execution time. And run it after reindexing .